# Insert values into array if it's empty / null?

Tags: c#

I have the following example strings:

```
,something2,something3,,something5
something1,,something3,something4,
```

I need to pull this into an array, but insert the "None" value for anything missing. (Different pieces of this string could be missing) For instance, it should be this when completed:

```
None,something2,something3,None,something5
something1,None,something3,something4,None
```

The length of the "array" would always be 5 values.

Anyone know how I would do that in C#? I can split the string into an array, but then I can't seem to update the array:

```
s.Split(char(',')) //How do I add the 'None' to the blank array parts?
```

If easier to add the "None" to the string and then split that to an array that would work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The followig code will split the string and replace empties with *None*:

```
var str = "something1,,something2,,something4";
var srtWithNone = str.Split(',').Select(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? "None" : x);
```

Make sure you import: `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each item is in the format 'something{n}' where {n} is number between 1 and 5

```
var str = "something1,,something3,something4,";
const int limit = 5;
var a = str.Split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a[i]))
    {
        a[i] = "None";
    }
}
var resultStr = string.Join(",", a);
```

Comment: This doesn't use any modern LINQ functionality

Comment: The question does not say it needs LINQ. Most of the the LINQ method internally does the same looping logic. LINQ is not magic. It is simply some optimize helper methods.

Comment: That's irrelevant. This solution is far less maintainable than it needs to be.

Comment: Not maintainable? Thats a pretty surprising claim, cmon man, this code is trivial.

Comment: Really? You've looked at the code above and you're saying that this is trivial? I mean, this might work, but it's far from ideal. If I came across this code in our code, I'd refactor straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should help you getting an output array containing your desired splitted strings in an array:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = ",something2,something3,,something5,something1,,something3,something4,";
    var splittedArray = s.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < splittedArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (splittedArray[i] == string.Empty)
        {
            splittedArray[i] = "None";
        }
    }
}
```

Once the above code runs then you would see that all empty parts in the array has got replaced with `None` as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var strings = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", null, "1","2", null, "zed" };

// replace the nulls with "None"
var noneStrings = strings.Select( strv => { return strv ?? "None"; });
Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(",", noneStrings) );
```

In the other direction:

```
var separators = new []{ "," };
var otherway = "a,b,c,,1,2,,zed";
var values = otherway.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None);

// [a,b,c,{null},1,2,{null},zed]

var fixedValues = values.Select( strv => { return String.IsNullOrEmpty(strv) ? "None" : strv; });

// [a,b,c,None,1,2,None,zed]
```

Should work a treat